# Sorting table from database through PHP

Tags: php, html, sorting, pdo

I need to sort my table from database by clicking on the header where is Price to sort it from Low to High and if I click again then sort High to Low. I am missing how to include this in php. I tried this solution but for some reason it is not working. Feel free repair this solution or offer something else

I am using PDO method

```
<?php
   include 'inc/header.php';
   $cars = $db->prepare("SELECT name, price FROM cars");
   $cars->execute();
   $cars = $cars->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Here is HTML:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>
         <a href="?orderBy=price">Price</a>
       </th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <?php  foreach($cars as $car):     ?>
      <tr>
       <td>
           <?php echo $car['name'];?>
       </td>
       <td>
          <?php echo $car['price'];?>€
       </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </tbody>
</table>

<?php
  $orderBy = array('price');    
  $order = 'type';
  if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
     $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
  }
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY '.$order;
)
?>
```

Comment: Try this with jQuery/JS, rather than PHP. You may want to look at Sortable Tabular Data: http://codepen.io/jakestuts/details/tGpju

Comment: You will have to make the `<a href=""></a>` a form. Because this currently just adds to the URL the `?orderBy=price` but it's not actually loading the page again. After creating the form, add the same .php url in the `action=""` with `$_GET` methord. If you don't want the page to load again, then you will have to play with jQuery.

Comment: look into DataTables

Comment: FYI, you are also missing DESC, or ASC keywords, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: table sorter reference http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: no need to do it in php.u can achieve this by using jquery table sorter

Comment: Why you're defining your query AFTER the actual output?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Jquery DataTables](https://datatables.net/), add an ID to your table then initialize Data Tables, it will allow you to sort your data by any column you want. Super easy to use and also it add cool features, such as pagination in your table for it not to be too long if you have many results. also options to export your table to pdf and other types easy.

```
<?php
include 'inc/header.php';
$cars = $db->prepare("SELECT name, price FROM cars");
$cars->execute();
$cars = $cars->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 ?>

<!-- include dataTables from the cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


 <table id="dataTable">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>
         <a href="?orderBy=price">Price</a>
       </th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
     <tbody>
       <?php  foreach($cars as $car):     ?>
      <tr>
       <td>
           <?php echo $car['name'];?>
       </td>
       <td>
          <?php echo $car['price'];?>€
       </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
   </tbody>
 </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

**DataTable Results :**

Your results will look like.

[image]

As you can see in the image you can easily sort by anything, with less hustle.

Comment: I am actually using Datatables. Though not in this example. Thing is I need a separate button in form of dropdown menu where I can choose what sort of filtering I want.  This menu would be located outside table. I am looking for a way how to sort columns through some php function.

Comment: why do u need php for this?

Comment: Not really sure if the php is the best way. I am only learning. I just need dedicated menu for sorting table. You think JS is better way to do it?

Comment: DataTables does have the feature u need I think they are the better option

Answer (score -1):

use table sorter plugin

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script> 
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
} 
); 
<table id="myTable" >
 <thead>
 <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>
     <a href="?orderBy=price">Price</a>  //u can give the table heading
   </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
   <?php  foreach($cars as $car):     ?>
  <tr>
   <td>
       <?php echo $car['name'];?>
   </td>
   <td>
      <?php echo $car['price'];?>€
   </td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

u can achieve table sorter by jquery in easiest way